# Does Wedderburn's Theorem hold constructively?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, constructive-mathematics

[Wedderburn's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem) states that every finite division ring is commutative. Perhaps even more surprising, this implies that every finite reduced ring is commutative. The proofs that I am aware of always follow a proof by contradiction. If a finite division ring is not commutative, its center is proper, blablabla, contradiction. Formally, this just proves that finite division rings are *not not* commutative, and we need the [law of the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) to finish the proof. This naturally leads to the following question:

**Question.** Does the Wedderburn Theorem hold constructively, i.e. in [Intuitionistic Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic)?

I believe that the answer is No. Incidentally, I have [recently proven](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.05301) "variants" of the Wedderburn Theorem constructively, and I want to know if there is literature on this topic.

Comment: Irrelevant comment: it is usually called "Wedderburn's little theorem" (to distinguish it from the Wedderburn-Artin theorem, I would guess).

Comment: Wedderburn's Theorem is going to boil down to a $\Pi^0_1$ statement (i.e., for all natural numbers, something computably checkable happens) by encoding finite rings as natural numbers. Heyting arithmetic is $\Pi^0_2$ conservative over Peano arithmetic, so assuming that the theory is provable in PA, it will be provable in HA.

Comment: Technically this is going to be sensitive to your definition of 'finite.' If by finite, you mean that the set is in bijection with an explicitly given natural number, then commutativity of the ring is going to satisfy excluded middle (in that you can just explicitly check whether the ring satisfies commutativity).

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but as far as I can tell, a finite structure is either commutative or noncommutative (by induction on its size, using decidability of equality). Hence the statement should be equivalent to its double negation.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek If 'finite' is interpreted broadly enough (specifically to allow for what constructive mathematicians would call 'sub-finite' sets), then it's less clear that it will be, although I suspect the theorem is probably still constructively provable with this broader definition.

Comment: @JamesHanson Well, in absense of an explicit disclaimer to the contrary in the question, I assume finite means finite, not subfinite.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I would agree, although I think it is worth mentioning since it's something that wouldn't necessarily occur to classical mathematicians.

Comment: Actually, $\neg\neg\forall x,y\in X\,xy=yx$ implies $\forall x,y\in X\,xy=yx$ assuming only the stability of equality on $X$ (which holds for subfinite $X$ as well).

Comment: The argument I came up with is that you can show that a subfinite division ring is a union of a directed family of finite division rings. Then you can argue that all locally finite division rings are commutative.

Comment: Ok maybe the proof of contradiction part can be made "constructive" because of finiteness, but I am also unsure about the rest of the proof. From a constructive point of view, the whole proof is magic. It does not really provide an insight _why_ the ring is commutative (but this is just my opinion).

Comment: Maybe an amusing note: Let a division ring coordinatize a projective plane. Then the plane is Desarguesian, and it is Pappian if and only if the division ring is commutative. So geometrically, Wedderburn's Theorem amounts to show that a finite Desarguesian plane is Pappian. As far as I know, there is no purely geometric proof for that.

Comment: The details of the proof do not really matter. As explained in the first comment by James Hanson, the theorem can be expressed as a $\Pi_1$ arithmetic statement (for division rings that are truly finite, hence decidable), and it clearly is provable in PA, hence it is provable in HA as well. The degree of magicness of the proof is irrelevant.

Comment: Having said that, the standard proof as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem#Proof looks perfectly constructive to me, keeping in mind that due to finiteness, the law of excluded middle holds for properties defined by quantification over $A$ (such as elementhood in $Z(A)$ or in $Z_x$).

Comment: I would accept this as an answer, even though I was hoping for something else (a proof which is constructive in a literal sense).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Indeed, this works for subfinite structures as you say — but not automatically for *Kuratowski-finite* structures (= things admitting a surjection from some finite set), another important notion of finiteness.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Is it not possible to constructively show that every Kuratowski-finite division ring is isomorphic to a finite division ring?

Comment: @JamesHanson: I don’t know, but it’s certainly not automatic!  By comparison, the analogous principle for plain rings (or many other kinds of structure) isn’t constructively provable since it implies LEM: Given a proposition $p$, take some non-trivial finite ring $R$, then take its quotient by the ideal $I_p = \{ x \in R \mid x = 0 \vee p\}$.  Now $R/I_p$ is K-finite, but if it’s finite, then it has decidable equality, so by checking whether $0 = 1$ in it, we can conclude either $p$ or $\lnot p$.  Did you have a specific argument in mind for the case of division rings?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I'm not completely sure about actually showing that they're isomorphic to finite division rings, but it really seems like you should be able to show that they're not non-commutative at least (perhaps non-uniformly in the size of the underlying finite set). Basically my intuition is that you should be able to give an explicit finite list of finite division rings and show that the original ring is not non-isomorphic to all of the rings on the list, establishing that it's not non-commutative (via the theorem for finite division rings).

Comment: But I guess the intuition for the stronger claim is just that finite division rings are such rigid objects (with no quotients, in particular) that you shouldn't really be able to do the same kind of encoding LEM trick.